# check if element in values also in key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the input dict as :-

```
classDict = {'G1': ['V1', 'G3', 'V2'], 
            'G2': ['G4', 'V3'], 
            'G3': ['V2'], 
            'G4': ['V3'], 
            'G5': ['G6'], 
            'G6': ['G2', 'G4', 'V3'], 
            'G7': ['reset']
            }
```

Which I need to convert into :-

```
finalStructure = {'G1': {'value':['V1','V2'],
                          'group':'G3'},         
                   'G2': {'value':'V3',
                          'group':'G4'},
                   'G3': {'value':'V2'}, 
                   'G4': {'value':'V3'},  
                   'G5': {'group':'G6'}, 
                   'G6': {'group':['G2', 'G4'],
                          'value':'V3'}, 
                   'G7': {'value':'reset'}
                   }
```

the problem here is that the values in the dicts are also keys at some places. I need to find them than add them to the new dictionary as a value. The real purpose behind this problem is to create flat class structure where the V1, V2 etc are the functions and G1 , G2 etc are classes. If a class G1 has another class G3 in its group then it should instantiate that class. 
Please don't use RE to differentiate 'G' and 'V' character as they are only pseudo names and the real names are completely different.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrshape - I have tried to go through multiple for loops where I was comparing the key using for key in dict.keys() with different values using for value in dict.values() . But I got stuck at multiple places and not able to think beyond. But thanks a lot for suggestion. Next time I will write my code also with the problem.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I should really write it in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. Next time try also to implement something by yourself.

```
def tofunnystructure(classDict):
    finalStructure = {}
    keys = set(classDict.keys())

    for key, vals in classDict.iteritems():
        newval = {}

        value = [val for val in vals if val not in keys]
        if value:
            newval['value'] = value[0] if len(value) == 1 else value

        groups = [val for val in vals if val in keys]
        if groups:
            newval['group'] = groups[0] if len(groups) == 1 else groups

        finalStructure[key] = newval

    return finalStructure
```

### Example

```
classDict = {'G1': ['V1', 'G3', 'V2'], 
            'G2': ['G4', 'V3'], 
            'G3': ['V2'], 
            'G4': ['V3'], 
            'G5': ['G6'], 
            'G6': ['G2', 'G4', 'V3'], 
            'G7': ['reset']
            }

print tofunnystructure(classDict)
```

*Output*

> {'G7': {'value': 'reset'}, 'G6': {'group': ['G2', 'G4'], 'value': 'V3'}, 'G5': {'group': 'G6'}, 'G4': {'value': 'V3'}, 'G3': {'value': 'V2'}, 'G2': {'group': 'G4', 'value': 'V3'}, 'G1': {'group': 'G3', 'value': ['V1', 'V2']}}

Comment: @enrico.basic Thanks a lot for this. I tried to go through comparison using dict.keys() and dict.values() but finally ended up with infinite loop... Thanks a lot for answer and suggestion. I should include my code also. Now I can go forward with my class structure